# Broadcast receiver not receiving intent.sender

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to implement broadcast receiver to determine which sharing option user clicked (via `Intent.createChooser`). The problem is broadcast receiver doesn't trigger `onReceive`. Here's the code :

```
object SharingHelper {

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
fun shareProduct(
    context: Context,
    product: BaseProduct,
    analyticsController: AnalyticsDataSource
) {
    analyticsController.sharedProduct(product)

    val packageManager = context.packageManager
    val availablePackages = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    availablePackages.type = "text/plain"
    val resInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(availablePackages, 0)
    val intentList = ArrayList<LabeledIntent>()
    //here I create pending intent for the broadcast receiver
    val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        context, 0,
        Intent(INTENT_RECEIVER_ACTION),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    )
    // here i just branch the intent, depending on which app I want to share with
    for (i in resInfo.indices) {
        val resolveInfo = resInfo[i]
        val packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName
        val sendIntent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            component = ComponentName(packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name)
            type = "text/plain"
        }
        if (packageName.contains(PACKAGE_FACEBOOK) || packageName.contains(PACKAGE_SMS)) {
            sendIntent.putExtra(
                Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                context.getString(R.string.check_out_this_product_share) + " " + product.productUrl
            )
        }
    else {
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, product.productUrl)
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, context.getString(R.string.check_out_this_product_share))
    }
    intentList.add(LabeledIntent(sendIntent, packageName, resolveInfo.loadLabel(packageManager), resolveInfo.icon))
}
    //here is the creation of Chooser
    val openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(Intent(),context.getString(R.string.share_via),pi.intentSender)
    val extraIntents = intentList.toTypedArray()
    openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, extraIntents)
    context.startActivity(openInChooser)
}

private const val PACKAGE_SMS="android.mms"
private const val PACKAGE_FACEBOOK="facebook"
const val INTENT_RECEIVER_ACTION="ACTION_RETURN_CHOSEN"
}
```

In my fragment I do the following:

```
private val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
     Log.d("xdd received", intent.toString())
    }
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    requireActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, 
IntentFilter(SharingHelper.INTENT_RECEIVER_ACTION))
```

And then I trigger share after clicking an icon:

```
override fun showShareDialog() {
    SharingHelper.shareProduct(requireActivity(), viewModel.baseProduct, analyticsController)
}
```

I have checked the broadcast receiver with `requireActivity().sendBroadcast` in `onViewCreated` and the receiver does receive the intent so I my guess is it's not connected to broadcast receiver registration, but rather some issues either with context, pending intent/createChooser or maybe some sort of permission I need to get the returning intent from other apps